# I want to use my iPad as a multi-video monitor

Tags: ipad

I have four wired video cameras on my RV, and would to replace the monitor with my old iPad.  Does anyone know the adapter(s) / software that would allow me to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Duet display might be what you're looking for
Duet Display by Rahul Dewan
https://appsto.re/us/qLNX3.i